# Reversing a 5-digit number is the prog. and it is giving a wrong output

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
 int i,a,n,r;
 n=12345;
 r=0;
 for(i=4;i>=0;i--)
 {
    a=n%10;
    n=n/10;
    r=r+a*pow(10,i);
 }

printf("%d",r);



  return 0;
}
```

Current output - 54320

Expected output - 54321

Please advise on what I may change in my code to reflect the correct output.

Comment: Do not use `pow(10,i)` for integer math.

Comment: pow use double and double are floating number so convert double to int is not perfect.

Comment: `r = r*10 + a;` instead of `r=r+a*pow(10,i);`  might work.

Comment: Also try to make the code *generic* by making use of `while` loop.

Comment: Why you have to do this as integers? Why you cannot do this via a character array?

Comment: @SouravGhosh sir i am new to c. i dont know arrays.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh, it's virtually the same algorithm to do what the OP wants as is it to convert the number to an array

Comment: @harshul1 1) I'm no "sir" :) 2) What's stopping you for learning?

Comment: @ikegami Well, there's no _storage_ mentioned, so I guess, a `snprintf()` and for loop might just do the work also. An alternative, not the only way.

Comment: @chux yea its working.thanks :)

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh, but why do all that extra work for nothing? No need to do the work twice when once is enough!

Comment: can please anyone advice that how can i do this prog. using pow? what changes should i do..please reply in a code form..thanks.! :)

Comment: You do not need pow for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pow` function returns a value of type `double`.  Because this is a floating point type, the result it returns will not always be exact.

What's happening in this case is that on the last iteration of the loop `pow(10, 0)` returns a value *slightly* less than 1.  This results in the right hand side of `r=r+a*pow(10,i);` to similarly be *slightly* less than 54321.  When this value is then assigned to `r`, which is of type `int`, it gets truncated.

Rather than using the `pow` function here, use the following:

```
r=r*10+a;
```

This shifts the current digits in `r` over by 1, then adds the newest digit to the end.  Also, rather than using a `for` loop, use `while (n>0)` instead.  Then it doesn't matter how many digits you have.

```
 while (n>0)
 {
    a=n%10;
    n=n/10;
    r=r*10+a;
 }
```

Comment: @harshul1 Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: please  advice that how can i do this prog. using pow? what changes should i do..please reply in a code form

Comment: @harshul1 You could call `round` on the result of `pow`.  Still, it's overkill for what you're doing.

Comment: how can i convert int to double..so that i can use pow? please code it!!please

Comment: No, using doubles instead of ints won't work. You would still be relying on doubles being exactly the same as they should be mathematically. Like dbush said, you'd have to round the double into an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified version of your algorithm:

```
void reverse_digits(int a) {
    int b = 0;

    while (a > 0) {
        b = b * 10 + a % 10;
        a /= 10;
    }

    printf("%d\n", b);
}
```

As for converting to character arrays as mentioned in the comments it's worth to notice that the convertion function will do similar arithmetic operations in order to convert the integer to character array, so doing the reversing using integers seems more convenient.